Upgrading VSCodium on ChromeOS
After (many) years of living in the DOS/Windows world, I'm trying to come to grips with ChromeOS. It is unclear to me whether my VSCodium installation will auto-update, like my Windows installation did, or if not, how to update the executable. Can one of you ChromeOS experts shed some light?
What I've tried so far, several months after a successful VSCodium installation, is the following:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
After a few moments I get "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded". What am I missing here?

If you referred to the Debian section of this document and installed it, your method should be correct.

@NorioYamamoto This solved my problem, because somehow I failed to add the repository correctly. Please post as an answer so that I can accept.

If you referred to the Debian section of this document and installed it, your method should be correct.
